# Intra-forest AD Migration with Sharepoint repermissions

Tags: document-migration

We are in mid way of Intra-forest AD Migration wherein the accounts with sid-history is getting migrated to the root domain. In nutshell we are collapsing the domains.
Sharepoint ENterprise Server 2010 is installed in the child domain.

After a user batch migration we are planning to use stsadm.exe -o migrate user or move-user to associate the permissions with the new migrated account.

We also have Mysite wherein users are uploading their photos and other stuff. How should be take care of My site profiles so that new migrated AD user has the same profile after migration on mysite.

Thanks in Advance!

Aman

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  I prefer stsadm -o migrateuser as you have to pass a user object (from Get-SPUser) to Move-SPUser, which is inconvenient.  The user's profiles will also migrate (which includes their MySite).  Make sure you sync from the top of the forest on down.  If you can't do that for some reason, disable the MySite Cleanup Job until your migration is finished and you're pointing your Sync connection at the single domain.