# Move users from child domain to parent domain

Tags: 2010, active-directory

We will soon move our user accounts from a child domain to the parent domain (admin/service accounts are already in the parent domain). Has anyone done something similar and are there any resources I can read up on? Any known implications and/or issues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What u mean by moving the user from child to parent domain....you migrating your SharePoint farm to new domain or servers are already in parent domain and you want to move contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For migrating moving a user in SharePoint you can use `Move-SPUser` command in PowerShell

```
Move-SPUser -Identity "DOMAIN\oldusername" -NewAlias "Domain\newusername"
```

[Technet link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729(v=office.14).aspx)

Here is a previous post about collapsing a forest. Indicating that you should do a top down migration of the users.

> You're on the right track. I prefer stsadm -o migrateuser as you have to pass a user object (from Get-SPUser) to Move-SPUser, which is inconvenient. The user's profiles will also migrate (which includes their MySite). Make sure you sync from the top of the forest on down. If you can't do that for some reason, disable the MySite Cleanup Job until your migration is finished and you're pointing your Sync connection at the single domain.

[Intra-forest AD Migration with Sharepoint repermissions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58349/intra-forest-ad-migration-with-sharepoint-repermissions)